# Python: Cosine Similarity between different size of NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I have a dictionary that has keys representing item_ids. Values of the dictionary is numpy array as follows: Prior to converting to dictionary data was in following format.

```
item_id tag_id_1, tag_id_2....  tag_id_n
1, 2323, 23423, 

{1: array([1, 3, 4, 1, 4]), 2: array([ 23. ,  35. ,  32.6,   1. ,   1. ,   1. ,   3. ,   5. ,   6. ]), 3: array([23, 35, 32]), 4: array([1, 5, 6])}
```

My goal is to find cosine similarity between keys and generate a dictionary as follows:

```
{1:[1,3], 2:[1,4]}
```

I was trying to use `TfidfVectorizer()` class of the `scikit learn` but the fit_transform method required to have list which means I have to take all my numpy array elements and append to a list. Once I do that its hard to track back the key of the each numpy array.

This is the route I was going to go:

```
matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(list_of_values)
for feature_idx in xrange(len(list_of_values)):
    cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix[0:feature_idx], matrix)
```

Using below dictionary How can I calculate cosine similarity between keys?

```
{1: array([1, 3, 4, 1, 4]), 2: array([ 23. ,  35. ,  32.6,   1. ,   1. ,   1. ,   3. ,   5. ,   6. ]), 3: array([23, 35, 32]), 4: array([1, 5, 6])}
```

Comment: How can you calculate cosine similarity between vectors of different dimension?

Comment: Doesn't makes sense to calculate cosine similarity between two vector of different dimensions.

Comment: so, each item_id is represent by tag_ids think as numbers in the np array is actually counts
item_id, tag_id_1, tag_id_2 etc

Comment: @JuniorCompressor just updated the question

Comment: You cannot compute cosine similarity between vectors of different length, as they belong to different vector spaces.  Not only that, given your data, you do not even know if the vectors to be compared share any dimensions at all...